# where SwingWorker should be in the class

Tags: java, swingworker

i have 2 class. One for GUI, and anther for reading file with updating it, to the `JTable` ,but it take long time. I would like to use `SwingWorker` to fix the issue. i found tutorials like this one [SwingWorker](https://wiki.palantir.com/pgdz/using-a-swing-worker.html), but still i don't get it. where do i have to use `SwingWorker`; is it in the reading class or GUI class, i never ever try it and i don't know any thing about it; I tried to google every where, buti need very simple example "the simplest) in other word where to start

Comment: Have you worked through this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html ?

Comment: that is right i have class for reading file information and it take to long i need SwingWorker but sun are giving me long tutorial tell you get lost

Comment: for example what is Interim Results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example. It is a program displaying a dummy progress in a `JLabel` :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lblProgress = new JLabel("0%");

    public GUI() {
       setTitle("Swing worker example");
       setSize(300, 200);    
       add(lblProgress);
       new Process().execute();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUI gui = new GUI();
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class Process extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {
            int count = 10000;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                int progress = (int) ((double) i/count*100.0);
                lblProgress.setText(progress + "%");
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            lblProgress.setText("Finished!");
        }
     }

 }
```

Comment: thanks but what is the first <String, String> can you give more explanation

Comment: The SwingWorker class is generic (i.e SwingWorker<T, V>). From API : 
T - the result type returned by this SwingWorker's doInBackground and get methods
V - the type used for carrying out intermediate results by this SwingWorker's publish and process methods

Comment: Look at the API for further details : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: ok cool i love what you said but let take you example as play ground your first String is because the return type of setText is String and the done() returning string can you explain this in you code

Comment: I've built this example and adapted it from one of my past project. The second String (V), as stated in the API, is the type of object that methods `publish` and `process` handles. Please read the API, it is very well documented and I don't want to paraphrase it.